# change imagePicker layout in xamarin.ios

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I am using a imagePicker in ios through Dependecy in my xamarin.forms project
The problem is that in ios devices I have this layout:

[image]

I can't see the status bar and the cancel button (which is at right) because they and the background are white..
Is there a way to change the top bar background of this imagepicker or some other solution for it?

Comment: this is normal behavior for a modal dialog.  Try launching the image picker from Mail or Messages and it will do the same thing

Comment: But the cancel button is white there. so, can't I change the color?

Answer (score 0):

```
imagePicker.NavigationBar.BarTintColor = UIColor.yourcolor
```

Solved the problem